# Let UIImageView in header section of UITableView overlap the content cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

I would like to have a header section in a table view with a logo and name. Now, I want the logo to overlap the image in the content cell below. I have attached an example of this below :-

[image]

Heres what I've tried so far, I've tried to make the header section half the size of (logo + upper and lower padding) -- this just cuts the logo in half

I also tried clipToBounds :-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 33.0
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell") as! FeedTableViewHeaderCell
    cell.designerNameLabel.text = "Vitamin A"
    cell.designerLogoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "zeko_small")
    cell.designerLogoImageView.clipsToBounds = false
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
    return cell

}
```

Comment: 1. Header section overlaps cells. 2. Header section has transparent zone.

Comment: Have you tried anything? please show the code if you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set `ImageViewFrameHeight` greater than `TableViewHeaderHeight` and In your `TableHeaderViewCell`, set

```
TableHeaderViewCell.contentView.clipsToSubview = NO.
```

This'll definitely help you in getting your result.

Visual guide from XCode 7:
[image]

Comment: there is no clipsToSubview in Xcode7 and Swift? i've done clipToBounds

Comment: @rohan23 You're going wrong somewhere, Please have a look at above pic and get it resolved..

Answer (score 0):

Please put this method and set your section's header height as you want.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100// return height which is greater than your image's height.
    }
```